# Can't start JBoss EAP 6.3 from standalone.sh

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, jboss6.x

I'm trying to start JBoss EAP 6.3 from command line running standalone.sh inside the bin folder and it returns: standalone.sh: command not found . I try to start the server from Red Hat Developer Studio and it works. I'm running it in Ubuntu.

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: Stupid question: have you tried `./standalone.sh`?

Comment: Hi StephaneM, yes I tried and the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

i am actually using keycloak developed by redhat community on the ubuntu which uses JBoss for hosting up 
so the command i used to boot up is ***./standalone.sh*** it works fine